# Photos rotated in output on some devices

Tags: android, react-native

When using [rn-doc-scanner-android](https://github.com/Diastorm/rn-doc-scanner-android),

the image file returned by `RNDocScanner.getDocumentCrop` is rotated by -90° on e.G

- Samsung S6/Android 7.0
- Sony XPERIA/Android 7.0
- Pocophone/Android 8.1.0

but not on Huawei P10 and P20 Lite/Android 8.0.0. It also is not rotated by my AVDs (Nougat - Pixel 2, Oreo - Nexus 9).

This is how I use the Module:

```
const image = await RNDocScanner.getDocumentCrop(true)
```

Why is this happening and how can this behaviour be made consistent?

Comment: you have to look at the exif orientation data of the photo and rotate/flip it according to how you need

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I'll have a look at that. I found this repo: https://github.com/francisco-sanchez-molina/react-native-exif. If the orientation is the solution to the problem, that lib should do the job

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan it appears there is no exif orientation property written by the module

Comment: are you capturing photo data via camera intent or are you using some react library for that or have you implemented a camera?

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan FWIU it [first starts a camera intent](https://github.com/Diastorm/rn-doc-scanner-android/blob/master/android/src/main/java/avwave/dev/docscanner/RNDocScannerModule.java#L54), and then some custom crop intenet from `devliving.online.cvscanner`, but I'm not too sure about that since I'm not a native android developer.

Comment: so in the camera intent onActivityResult, you can check whether there is exif data using android's native ExifInterface functionality and then rotate the photo before saving.if there isn't you'll just have to ask the user to rotate the function manually. most cameras save the rotation in exif data

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-native-image-resizer to rotate the image in desired orientation.

```
import {RNDocScanner} from 'rn-doc-scanner';
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';

const scanAndRotateHandler=async()=>{
const image=await await RNDocScanner.getDocumentCrop(true);
const response=await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(JSON.stringify(image), 400, 400, 'PNG', 100, 90, null);
console.log(response.uri); // the uri is your rotated image by 90 degrees 
  
}
scanAndRotateHandler();
```

Comment: but how do you find out the desired orientation if the scanner does not save exif data?

Comment: If I let the client decide how to save the scan, I'm gonna have a bad time